# how to echo an xml in php?

Tags: php, xml, echo

I have this function and I need to echo an XML but it doesnt work. what is the problem?

```
static function login_xml($ERROR_ID,$SESSION_ID)
{
  echo "<BR>IN LOGINXML<BR>"; 


  echo '<xml version="1.0">'.
  '<response>log_in</response><parameters><error>'.$ERROR_ID.'</error><session>'
  .$SESSION_ID.'</session></parameters></xml>';
 }
```

I tried with header('Content-type: text/xml'); before echo, that doesnt work either. What can I do?

Comment: Seems like you want to echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>', and add a sensible root element

Comment: i wanna echo the whole concatenated string.

Comment: sure, it's just that having a root element called "xml" confused me, since the use of the 'version="1.0"' attribute seems oddly similar to the ubiquitous XML Declaration syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the line

```
echo "<BR>IN LOGINXML<BR>";
```

XML should have only one root element, that is <xml> in your case

Comment: there is only one root, that is <xml version .. > close by </xml>  it doesnt work, maybe coz i got many echoes from other functions before this?

Comment: Exactly, there must be nothing echoed before/after your <xml>...</xml>, and header('Content-type: text/xml'); to be sent before xml

Comment: I`ve cleared everything before it, it doesnt work in this file, but i duplicated the same code in a simple script and works like a charm.